# How to package JavaScript as a .NET Internet Explorer 9 Plugin?

Tags: javascript, .net, internet-explorer, plugins

**How to .NET package JavaScript as an Interner Explorer 8/9 Plugin, with the JS to be included in all IE browser pages?**

I have recently finished writing JavaScript code for a browser addon, which basically runs on page-load via a JS load event listener, and for given domains it then checks for certain elements in the DOM and adds new relevant elements(i.e. information) to the page.

Since the JavaScript only reads/affects the HTML DOM independently (and does not need any toolbar buttons or anything else) the JS purely needs adding to the browser's webpages.

I have packaged the code to work with Firefox and Chrome and those are both working well, and I can run the code for IE in 'bookmarklet' form without problems, but I would like to learn how to package JavaScript as an actual .NET .MSI addon/plugin that will install for the current Internet Explorer 8/9.

Does anyone know of a suitable guide or method I might refer to please? I have tried searching online for tutorials but most walkthroughs refer to writing the plugin body itself (usually in other languages) and are thus not regarding packing existing JS.

I hope someone might have the solution please?

Note: Someone packaged an old version for me as a MSI installer for Internet Explorer 7 a year ago, which installed into Program Files with a `plugin.dll` `plugin.tlb` and `plugin.InstallState` plus `BandObjectLib.dll` `Interop.SHDocVw.dll` and `Microsoft.mshtml.dll` if that is useful.

Edit: Does anyone else know of any other options please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/ and http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/deployment.php they sell a package for this. It will cost you 200 dollar, but will save you allot of time (atleast, It saved me allot of time :) ).

Comment: They do look good, thank you for the link. I've sent them an email to see if their product is suitable to packaging JavaScript includes.

Comment: The company has confirmed that their product is exactly what I was looking for, so I will be splashing out to give it a whirl. Thank you again for the tip! :)

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't have a mechanism for this, there simply is no JavaScript based extension ecosystem (though there are other methods to create extensions) for those browsers, yet.  IE8 won't be getting one, you can pretty much guarantee that, IE9...we'll see what happens.

The closest JavaScript option available to you would be [bookmarklets](http://www.bookmarklets.com/about/), which have much more limited functionality...but it's what's available.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I knew someone who packaged an early version for IE7 for me last year with an msi installer so I was hoping it would be possible.

Comment: Does anyone else know of a possible solution please?

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial to create a plugin that loads JS-Code

http://shout.setfive.com/2012/05/01/internet-explorer-extension-quick-start-and-skeleton/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid (and downvoted) if the linked page changes. See [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for why it is important.